# Intermittent error when setting matrix uniform for shader using member function

Tags: c++, opengl

The code below wasn't working for 2 days and after I've fiddled around with it, created new functions, rewrote them, deleted them and now, strangely, it works! I'm afraid there's a fundamental c++ error and my noob brain can't see it.

```
void Shader::SetMat4(const char* key, const glm::mat4 &value) {
  uint loc = glGetUniformLocation(id, key); // id is the program id stored as member var
  glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(value));
}
```

If I set the uniform directly in the calling function instead of doing `shader->SetMat4` it was working, but this just refused to work.

I suspect it has something to do with the way I'm passing a `mat4` reference and in the way `value_ptr` returns `const *mat4::value_type`, but I don't see it. And now I'm afraid there's something in my code that will bite me a year from now :|.

Comment: That code is fine, the const reference will live long enough that `glm::value_ptr` is correct (although I would prefer to only call `glGetUniformLocation` once, when you create the shader, it won't hurt anything). If you are experiencing a bug, the cause of the bug is somewhere else. Maybe the wrong program is active.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that! Is `glGetuniformLocation` expensive? If so, then that's a good idea. Regarding the program, there's only one shader and one program at the moment which I'm using for all objects. So that shouldn't be it. But good to know that there's nothing wrong with the way I'm using it for now.

Comment: If you suspect of errors, retrive the error code after each OpenGL command using `glGetError()`

Comment: In my experience debugging spurious OpenGL problems, the most probable cause is OpenGL functions being called without or inside the wrong OpenGL context. Code that's being called through a constructor or destructor is prone to these bugs, due to being called in automatic allocation/deallocation (think scoped instances, RAII, shared_ptr/weak_ptr). Unfortunately OpenGL contexts are a global-scope, thread local state and accurately tracking it, without careful interjection of bookkeeping code in all codepaths that call `⬚glMakeCurrent` either comes with performance penalties or is painful.